# Is it possible that Accept return a same socket value for different tcp connections on the same machine

Tags: linux, sockets

Is there possible that accept() (on redhat Enterprise 4/linux kernel 2.6) return a same socket value for different tcp connections from the same process of a same application and same machine?

I am so surprised that when I got such a result that many connections have the same socket value on server side when I checked the log file!! How is it possible?!!

By the way, I am using TCP blocking socket to listen.

```
    main(){
        int fd, clientfd, len, clientlen; 
        sockaddr_in address, clientaddress;

        fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        ....
        memset(&address, 0, sizeof address);

        address.sin_address = AF_INET;
        address.sin_port = htons(port); 
        ....
        bind(fd, &address, sizeof address);
        listen(fd, 100);
        do {
             clientfd = accept(fd, &clientaddress, &clientlen); 

             if (clientfd < 0) {
             ....
             } 

             printf("clientfd = %d", clientfd);  

             switch(fork()){
             case 0:

                    //do something else
                    exit(0);
             default:
                     ...
             }


          } while(1);
    }
```

my question is that why `printf("clientfd = %d");`   prints a same number for different connections!!!

Comment: please show some source code... and: what exactly is the problem ?

Comment: thanks... the numbers get reused... so if a connection has been closed and a new connection comes in the OS can reuse that number (within the same process)... IMHO there is no problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If server runs in multiple processes (like Apache with mpm worker model), then every process has its own file descriptor numbering starting from 0.

In other words, it is quite possible that different processes will get exact same socket file descriptor number. However, fd number it does not really mean anything. They still refer to different underlying objects, and different local TCP ports.

Answer (score 1):

The socket is just a number.It is a hook to a data structure for the kernel.

BTW TCP uses IP. Look up the RFC

Answer (score 0):

That printf() doesn't print any FD at all. It's missing an FD parameter. What you are seeing could be a return address or any other arbitrary junk on the stack.

Comment: I did miss one parameter in the statement and corrected it now, though this is not the real problem I am concerning, thanks for pointing out it.